# Getting around single quotes when adding variable to SQL query

Tags: karate

My original query in the DB is:
select person_id from users where email = 'markq@test.com' and it runs successfully in karate as such.

The issue is when I try to replace the email with a dynamic variable from a previous response.

- def query = DB.readRow("select person_id from users where email =  " + randomEmail)
- def dbResult = DB.readRow(query)

It needs single quotes, like
("select person_id from users where email =  " + 'randomEmail') but Karate gives me a Bad SQL grammar error when I try that.

I have tried and failed with:
'(randomEmail)'
''

I also tried the replace method, but no love there either.

Also, can someone point me to a good example of converting the SQL response into a string so its printable?